# Correct addition of OR logical operator

Tags: javascript, checkbox, logical-operators

I am using a script for inputting musical note selection (C, C#, etc) via checkboxes to find the name of the chord. With one octave it works perfectly.

I have 12 checkboxes with the following string as an example:

```
if (
    cb[0].checked == true
    && cb[1].checked == false
    && cb[2].checked == false
    && cb[3].checked == false
    && cb[4].checked == true
    && cb[5].checked == false
    && cb[6].checked == false
    && cb[7].checked == true
    && cb[8].checked == false
    && cb[9].checked == false
    && cb[10].checked == false
    && cb[11].checked == false
) {
    alert('C');
}
```

This works fine when boxes C0, C4 and C7 are checked, and of course not when any other combination is checked.

Now, I want to add an extra octave. I've added a 13th box (C12) as an optional alternative to C0.

I tried adding the `||` operator as follows:

```
if(cb[0].checked==true||cb[12]==true&&cb[1].checked==false...
```

but this doesn't work.

Strangely, just adding box C12 to the page without changing the script string at all, when I select boxes C12, C4 and C7 I get the result alert 'G♯/A♭m', which I should get only for this string:

```
else if (
    cb[8].checked == true
    && cb[9].checked == false
    && cb[10].checked == false
    && cb[11].checked == true
    && cb[0].checked == false
    && cb[1].checked == false
    && cb[2].checked == false
    && cb[3].checked == true
    && cb[4].checked == false
    && cb[5].checked == false
    && cb[6].checked == false
    && cb[7].checked == false
) {
    alert('G♯/A♭m');
}
```

which I don't understand, as that string contains no cb[12] and only 2 of the 3 `true` checkboxes required.

Is there a correct way I can add this `||cb[12]==true` thread so that either C0 or C12 get the same result?

Thanks for reading this long question! Any advice appreciated.

Comment: `&&` is to `||` as `*` is to `+` — you have to parenthesize appropriately

Comment: Thanks for the info... but would you mind letting me know the appropriate parentheses in this case?

Comment: I tried:

 if((cb[0].checked==true||cb[12].checked==true)&&cb[1].checked==false... ...) 

but I really don't know what I'm doing here.

Comment: Actually, that did work (I had made a mistake the first time), so thanks very much @Pointy for your help.